# SQL Alchemy - delete orphan from multiple one to one relationships on one entity

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, cascading-deletes

I got defined on one table these two one to one relationships.

```
    home_lineup_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("Lineup.id"))
    home_lineup = relationship("Lineup", foreign_keys=[home_lineup_id], cascade="all, delete-orphan", single_parent=True)
    guest_lineup_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("Lineup.id"))
    guest_lineup = relationship("Lineup", foreign_keys=[guest_lineup_id], cascade="all, delete-orphan", single_parent=True)
```

And quite obviously I´d like the delete orphan fuctionality to work. This solution rather oddly deletes only half the Lineups presumably ones from the first relationship.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Edit: I´m using PostgreSQL.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your issue using mssql+pyodbc:// and was unable to do so. Can you provide a [mcve] to illustrate? Note that SQLite can be confusing when it comes to foreign keys because by default it *creates* them but it does not *enforce* them.

Comment: I´m using PostgreSQL. I should´ve mentioned that. - But that shouldn´t matter because this is AFAIK ORM level implementation that shouldn´t depend on database. @GordThompson

Comment: Works for me with PostgreSQL, too. [This code](https://pastebin.com/FcamGR9q) does, anyway.

Comment: Thanks. It´s perhaps a bit embarrassing but it turned out to be a typo - I had function that assigned both relationships - but after some refactoring I assigned both entities to the same relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this code is completely fine and works as intended. It was just a typo elsewhere.